# Change .Net WebProject to solution with subprojects

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, perforce

Want to ask you about difficult case with perforce.

So what do I have. There is a .Net WebSite project. It is under version control in perforce.
The task is to have a solution which will contain this project (think that it also must be converted to WebApplication) and one more other subproject.

The question is next: is it possible to make this changes and do not corrupt perforce history?
For more details I am adding minimal explanation:
For ex. there is something like this in p4

```
    -WebProject (folder)
    --WebProject.csproject(VS project file)
    --some other files.....
```

And as I understand after changes it must be smth like this

```
    -WebSolution (folder)
    --WebSolution.sln (VS solution file)
    --WebProject (folder contained previous web site)
    --NewProject(project that should be added to solution)
```

So is it possible to do changes and have normal web site files history in new implementation?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to make this changes and do not corrupt perforce
>   history?

Yes, you can preserve the history.

As long as you *integrate* files when you move them history will be preserved. This feels counter intuitive, since you're not moving chages to another brach or anything like that. Still it's the integrate command you will want to use. To move a file with history in perforce, right click it in the depot view and click "Integrate..." and then just type in the new name. You should also mark the old file for deletion.

In newer versions of P4 you can do this using the "move" command, see more information on both methods [here](http://kb.perforce.com/article/7/renaming-files).

In your case you wan't to move the entire folder, so just use *integrate* or *move* on the folder in the depot view.

You will probably also want to change some files, e.g. the vsproj-file. I recommend doing this in a separate changelist.